# How to upload image and show in web page using PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
<body bgcolor = "pink">
<form method = "post" action = "" enctype = "mutlipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" name="up" >
    <input type = "submit" value = "upload" name="submit">
    <input type = "reset" value = "clear">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_FILES);
//echo "</pre>";
$name=addslashes($_FILES['up']['name']);
$image=addslashes($_FILES['up']['tmp_name']);
$image=file_get_contents($image);
$image=base64_encode($image);
echo $image;
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con, "pic");
$res = mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO image(name, image) VALUES ('$name', '$image')");
if($res)
{
    echo "Image uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed to save image in Database";
}
$qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM image");
echo "<table width = 450 border = 5 bordercolor = red align = center bgcolor = green cellpadding = 12>";
echo "<th>Sno</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Image</th>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($qry)) {
    $src = '<img width = 250 height = 125 src = "data:image; base64, '.$row[2].'">';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>".$row[0]."</th>";
    echo "<th>".$row[1]."</th>";
    echo "<th>".$src."</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
         }
     ?>
</body>
```

Here I am using image upload and show in table, I got below error.

- **Notice: Undefined index: up in C:\wamp\www\DMS\image.php**

Note: Here i written PHP and html code in same page.

How to solve this problem. Please help me

Comment: It's obvious you don't have such an index as `up` in your array. No file with this name was given. Try to `var_dump` FILES array and see what it have.

Comment: array (size = 0) empty. while
 var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: Not working how it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<body bgcolor = "pink">
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="up">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    <input type = "reset" value = "clear">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($_FILES);
    //echo "</pre>";
    $name=addslashes($_FILES['up']['name']);
    $image=addslashes($_FILES['up']['tmp_name']);
    $image=file_get_contents($image);
    $image=base64_encode($image);
    echo $image;
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "pic");
    $res = mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO image(name, image) VALUES ('$name', '$image')");
    if($res)
    {
        echo "Image uploaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to save image in Database";
    }

    $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM image");
    echo "<table width = 450 border = 5 bordercolor = red align = center bgcolor = green cellpadding = 12>";
    echo "<th>Sno</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Image</th>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($qry))
    {
        $src = '<img width = 250 height = 125 src = "data:image; base64, '.$row[2].'">';
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$row[0]."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$row[1]."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$src."</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    }
    exit();
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Hassaan I got . Why you are using exit(); . I wrote exit() in last it works Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kiran `exit()` is not necessary you can remove it. I just write it for testing purpose.

Comment: Did you find any error in my php code then what did you changed in my code.

Comment: @Kiran the issue was in your HTML. I just rewrite the HTML

Comment: Ok got it yar @Hassaan

Comment: @Kiran please accept my answer if it solve the issue you are facing.